# Getting all objects with same key from a MultiValueMap

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-collection

I have a [`MultiValueMap<Integer, Path>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html) from which I am trying to get [*print for the purpose of this question*] out all the paths which were put in the map using the same key.

This is my current solution:

```
MultiValueMap<Integer, Path> duplicates = duplicateFinder.getDuplicates();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry: duplicates.entrySet()) {
  final Integer key = entry.getKey();
  final Object obj = entry.getValue();
  for (Object o: (LinkedList)((ArrayList)entry.getValue()).get(0))
    System.out.println(o);
  System.out.println();
}
```

I feel my solution is dangerous (casting and magic number 0) and would like to avoid it.
How can I achieve the desired result in a more readable/safe manner?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Error:(35, 41) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.nio.file.Path>

Comment: How do you mean by not declared as `MultiValueMap<Integer, Path>`? The decleration is shown in the first line of my code listing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I agree that would make sense, but that's not what the API documentation appears to support.

Comment: I found the error. It was elsewhere in the program.  `MultiValueMap<Integer, Path>` was being populated with `LinkedList`s containing `Path`s instead of `Path`s. I feel its strange that it does not ensure that whatever I try putting in there is a `Path`.

Comment: @Pétur It's because they've inexplicably made it implement `Map`; They couldn't make it implement `Map<K, V>` because then an entry would be an `Entry<K, V>`. They couldn't make it implement `Map<K, Collection<V>>` because then the `put` method would need a `Collection<V>` not a `V`, so to get round this they've made it implement `Map<K, Object>`, which takes away any chance of type-safety. It looks like you should use the Guava version instead.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Thank you for the good explaination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry set seems to be declared with an unfortunate signature. But you could iterate over the keys instead, and call `getCollection` for each:

```
for (Integer key : duplicates.keySet()) {
    Collection<Path> paths = duplicates.getCollection(key);
    System.out.println("Paths for " + key);
    for (Path path : paths) {
        System.out.println("  " + path);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

(Note that Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) would allow you to use `duplicates.asMap().entrySet()` instead, and each entry would have a `Collection<V>` as a value...)